# editing in /var/www/html

Tags: php, apache, web-applications

I am not much of a web developer, so apologies in advance for this dumb question.

I have a test server (Centos 6.3) with LAMP set up for me to play around. From what I understand, the server executes whatever is in /var/www/html directory. How do you edit source files in that directory ? Do you do a sudo vim "foo.php" each time you want to fix something (or add something ) ? I'd imagine that would be a pain when you are building a complex application with many files and directories .

Comment: Yes, I would do a sudo vim for each file I would edit. Not sure if you are trolling a n00b.

Answer (score 7):

This is what worked for me. For the record this is a Centos 6.3 server running LAMP (On Rackspace).

First, I found out that apache runs as user "apache" and group "apache" on centos systems. In other distros, I believe it runs as "www-data" in group "www-data". You can verify this by looking at /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf. We need to change ownership of /var/www to this user. Replace "apache" below with "www-data" if that is the case for you.

```
chown -hR apache:apache /var/www
```

Now lets make it writable by the group:

```
chmod -R g+rw /var/www
```

Add yourself to the apache group:

```
usermod -aG apache yourusername
```

Replace apache with www-data in the above if thats the case for you.

Now log out and log in - you can now edit the files, ftp them to this directory or do whatrever you want to do.

Comments welcome. TNX!

Comment: That's a straight forward solution.

Answer (score 3):

There are many approaches to modifying and deploying websites/web apps.

CentOS 6 is, by default, accessible with SSH2 on port 22. If you are on Windows you can use a combination of [PuTTY](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/) and [WinSCP](http://winscp.net/eng/index.php) (to manage your server, and its files, respectively). If you're on Linux or Mac OS X, SSH is already built into your system and can be accessed with Terminal. I find that using SSH is favourable over other methods because of how widely supported, secure and lightweight it is.

You'll also need a decent text editor or IDE to edit the files if you want proper syntax detection. There's tons of choices, my favourites are [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) and Sublime Text 2. Not to say that I haven't edited my PHP files from time to time using the nano text editor package directly in PuTTY (`yum install nano`).

If you're using a edit-save-upload approach, just remember to **back up your files regularly**, you will find out the hard way if you fail to do so. Also, never use root unless you need to. Creating a user solely to modify your websites is good practice (`adduser <username>`, and give that user write access to `/var/www/html`).

To answer your second question:

Once you get into heavier web development you will probably want to use something like [Git](http://git-scm.com/). Deploying with git is beyond the scope of this question so I won't get into that. In brief, you can set it up so your development environment sits locally and you can use a combination of `git commit` and `git push` to deploy.

Answer (score 2):

I use a FTP client (FileZilla) to download files, edit them and then re-upload them. If you're a one (wo)man show, and on a test setup and just playing around to learn, this is probably sufficient. With more than 1 person, or going to a (test and) production setup, you should look at some more control with svn like @Markus mentioned in another answer.

Comment: awesome, yes I am a one man show and tinkering around to learn.

Answer (score 1):

You should change the permissions of that directory (with `chmod`) so you have write permissions, and can then read and write to that directory. Then, you don't need `sudo`.

Answer (score -2):

dude. read up on version control and source code control systems like subversion and git. the idea is to develop on your machine, revision control the result, then deploy a known working version on the production server.

Comment: "dude", thanks. I am learning the ropes. There is no production server for now. My question relates to developing on "my" machine. Sorry if this was a stupid question.